# Yum install return bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, centos, yum

I tried to do `yum install zlib-devel` I got

[image]

How can I fix this so I can use my `yum install`again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yum is broken because a python problem.  You can use the rpm utility to reinstall python, or to manually install zlib-devel.

Yum ins't a requirement for installing packages.  It just makes it more convenient.  You can manually download any rpm package for CentOS.  I prefer to find what I need using [this search engine](http://rpm.pbone.net).

```
# Find a download url for zlib-devel rpm on rpm.pbone.net for
# centos6 and download to your server:
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.centos.org/6.8/os/x86_64/Packages/zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64.rpm

# Install the rpm package
rpm -i ./zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

At this point, you may be told you are missing dependencies.  Yum handles that for you automatically.  But yum is broken :-(  So download each of those dependency packages and install them the same way.  Then try to install zlib-devel again.

You can re-install the python rpm package as well, using rpm from the command line.  Check which python version is on your server using `rpm -q python` or some variation.  Then download the rpm package for python, and installing it manually.